# How to detect when android monkey test catches ANR or Error

Tags: android, android-logcat, android-monkey

I made a Jenkins job to continually test Android Monkey.
My purpose is to find hidden errors of exceptions.
I ran it 420 times and cannot find any error.

Is there a way I can find errors or exceptions automatically and save log file?

Answer (score 0):

ADB monkey generates crash log to STDERR.
However, sometimes, it goes to STDOUT.

So, if you check both STDERR and STDOUT, you can get crashlog and by checking the size of STDERR, you can identify if there was a crash or not.